# AVAssetSession init?(asset: AVAsset, presetName: String) returns nil

Tags: ios, swift

My offending line of code is

```
let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: avAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)!
```

And the init is returning nil.

Nil is a meaningless return value and it is not explained in the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avassetexportsession/1389367-init

How should I handle and diagnose a nil return value here?

Comment: Is the M4A preset listed in the array returned by [exportPresets(compatibleWith: avAsset)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avassetexportsession/1390567-exportpresets)?

Comment: Did you experience this running on device or on simulator? I have run into the same issue running on an iPhone 7 simulator, `AVAssetExportSession.allExportPresets()` returns an empty array, while it returns the usual presets when running on an iPhone 6s simulator. My assumption thus would be that this is a simulator bug, but it would be good to confirm this works on device (iPhone 7) as expected.

Comment: It is not. `let presets = AVAssetExportSession.exportPresets(compatibleWith: avAsset)` returns an empty array.